# Leomund's Tiny Hut and familiars

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

If I cast *[Leomund's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/leomunds-tiny-hut) [Tiny Hut(LTH)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut)*, the spell ends if I leave it. Spells and other magical effects can't pass through the barrier.

Can I cast spells from my familiar outside LTH?

If I switch my mind to my familiar inside the hut, and the familiar leaves LTH, does LTH end?

If I can switch to my familiar outside LTH, have I left the Hut, even though my body is still inside?

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I believe Nathan S has the correct answer here and rpgstar does not.  Nathan S has not been seen for more than a year and is unlikely to elaborate the case for telepathy.  I would love to see [your answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133628/23547) to [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133610/which-features-of-a-wizards-familiar-if-any-are-considered-magical) modified to answer this question here.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes. You can move a familiar outside LTH

The duration of the *find familiar* spell is instantaneous

> Many spells are instantaneous. The spell harms,
> heals, creates, or alters a creature or an object in a way
> that can’t be dispelled, because its m agic exists only
> for an instant. (phb 203)

meaning that after the initial casting there is **no active spell to dispel**.

## Yes. You can cast spells through the familiar

Yes, while you are inside the LTH, you can cast spells through your familiar as the range of the spells is touch. The spell is cast by the caster with an origin at the familiar and has a range of touch. Never does a spell pass through the barrier. The spell does not pass through the barrier effect and is therefore not blocked.

These have been talked about in [this question about what part of a familiar is magical](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133610/which-features-of-a-wizards-familiar-if-any-are-considered-magical)

## LTH wont end

Having the familiar inside during the casting means that it won't exceed the creature limit and the familiar moving outside the hut won't remove the hut.

## You are still inside the Hut.

D&D counts bodies, not minds. You are still there unless **you** move out. Your familiar isn't you. Therefore, the hut will remain intact. (The DM may rule that your mind must be inside the dome in order to maintain the hut, but by RAW it doesn't.)

Comment: I don't think the comparison to *antimagic field* holds up. AMF is not a barrier, it is a region where magic is suppressed. LTH, on the other hand, does not suppress spells, but it does explicitly create a barrier that blocks them.

Comment: @RyanThompson the spell being cast does not go *through* the barrier. the spell is cast by the caster with an origin at the familiar and is a range of touch. never does a spell pass through the barrier.

Comment: @RyanThompson I understand what you mean. The rest of the answer holds up without the comparison though. I have removed the comparison.

Comment: I think you should also rephrase or remove the last sentence. LTH does not produce an anti-magic effect, nor does it dispel anything, so using those terms just confuses the issue.

Comment: Also, unrelated to the above, your answer currently only addresses the first part of the question. For completeness, it should also answer the part about using the familiar's senses.

Comment: @RyanThompson I have changed the wording, you are right the LTH spell does not dispel spells nor does it apply an anti-magic field though it is somewhat similar there are key differences. also i have reread the question and attempted to answer the sections I missed.

Comment: Why does there need to be an "active spell to dispel"?  Tiny Hut clearly states "Spells and other magical effects".  If the effect were limited to only spells, it would just say "spells", but it is clearly written to have a broader meaning.

Comment: Also as I said in my answer the duration is over before the familiar leaves therefor there is no active spell. Active being still during the duration

Comment: @rpgstar Are the abilities granted by the find familiar spell magic?  If not, why are the abilities granted by a spell not magic?

Comment: @Grosscol the link I gave explains most of your question. None of the familiar is magical. Abilities included.

Comment: @rpgstar that's a link to an answer for a different system.  The ability to cast through the familiar is granted to the caster by the spell.  Why is this different than the fly speed granted by flight?

Comment: The duration of flight is not instantaneous whereas find familiar is. If find familiar said "you summon I familiar for X days" then there's would be a magical effect.

Comment: @rpgstar the effects of spells with a duration of instantaneous are not magical effects?

Comment: @Grosscol I will add this quote in a further comment because I'm on my phone but if you refer to the part of chapter 10 of the phb where it talks about duration then you would find that it says the magic exists only for an instant. Therefore anything after that instant is not magical.

Comment: Will add pg number and quote when I'm on my computer

Comment: "Many spells are instantaneous. The spell harms,
heals, creates, or alters a creature or an object in a way
that can’t be dispelled, because its magic exists only
for an instant." pg 203 of the phb

Comment: @Grosscol the effects are magical but only for the instant in which the casting occurs, after which they are not magical

Comment: I see. That might be a useful addition to the answer. Clearly indicates a rationale for the effects of the spell not being magical.

Comment: @Grosscol done just that earlier :)

Answer (score 0):

You’re missing one technical factor.  The spell creates a hemisphere, therefore any spell that isn’t directed from you i.e. burning hands, but as per find familiar feature ..

> ... your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell.

So the class feature treats the familiar as the caster .. ergo the spell isn’t going *through* the dome.  It would depend on the specifics of each spell to see what could be cast or not, but I feel that this would work accordingly.

Comment: I think the casting through the familiar is a function of the find familiar spell, and not a class feature.

Answer (score -1):

## No, you can't cast spells or similar via familiar

The relevant part of the spell's description is (PHB, pg 255):

> Spells and other magical effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it.

I'd say switching to your familiar's mind counts as a magical effect, and casting spells through it certainly counts (assuming the familiar is outside the dome and you are within). However, the familiar should still be able to pass through the dome and act, just not using your magical abilities.

To address your question "*If I switch my mind to my familiar inside the hut, and the familiar leaves LTH, does LTH end?*" directly, switching your mind up your familiar's would end as the familiar leaves the dome (since that is a magical effect), but LTH itself would not end unless you physically left it.

Again, for "*If I can switch to my familiar outside LTH, have I left the Hut, even though my body is still inside?*", you wouldn't be able to do this as you're trying to use a magical effect outside the dome.

Comment: What's wrong about this answer?

Comment: It doesn't say that no magic from one side can affect anything on the other. My reading of "magical effects can't extend through the dome" is that it mainly refers to AOE spells (i.e. if the point of origin is outside, nothing inside is affected and vice versa). I'm not sure whether using the pre-existing connection between you and your familiar counts as extending a magical effect through the dome. (Note that *find familiar*'s duration is instantaneous.) I think whether delivering a touch spell via your familiar counts as casting through the dome is also ambiguous.

Comment: I've asked a separate question to address whether any of the familiar's special features are magical: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133610/which-features-of-a-wizards-familiar-if-any-are-considered-magical

Comment: @RyanThompson if you want that question to be helpful here, you need to ask whether those features are magical effects. Asking whether those features are magical is not precise enough.

Comment: I would love to hear a more thorough explanation for why this has been so downvoted aside from "my reading... is that it mainly refers to AOE spells".  A telepathic connection to a summoned creature  that can facilitate spellcasting absolutely sounds like a magical effect that is extending through the dome to me.

Comment: Consider adding a supporting citation or statement about why seeing through the familiar's eyes is a magical effect and not something like a class feature.  I think this is supported in that the seeing through the familiar senses is specified as an effect of the find familiar spell.

Comment: Refer to the Monster Manuel for the explicit clarification that telepathy is magical, and cite the wording of the Find Familiar spell describing the communication between wizard and familiar as telepathy, to improve this answer.