# Does Conjuration work from inside Leomund's Tiny Hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

(Leomund's) Tiny Hut says

> Creatures and objects within the dome when you cast this spell can move through it freely. All other creatures and objects are barred from passing through it. Spells and other magical effects can’t extend through the dome or be cast through it.

Suppose a caster capable of summoning a creature from another plane (Find Steed, Find Familiar, Conjure X, Summon Y) is around a *Hut*.

So...
Creatures may not be conjured outside the hut by a caster inside, or *vice versa* (since the ranged casting would count as casting "though" the hut).

And...
Creatures successfully conjured inside the hut cannot leave (since they were not present at the time of casting)

And...
Creatures successfully conjured outside the hut cannot enter (since they were not present at the time of casting)

But...
**Can a creatures be conjured inside the hut by a caster inside the hut?**

Does making the connection to the plane from which the creature is summoned count as casting *through* the hut?

Does it matter which plane?  (for example, there is lots of support for the idea that the Ethereal Plane is "no distance" from the prime, but I haven't found that for other planes and most creatures would not be summoned from the Ether.

I have seen the distinction between spells like *Dimension Door* not allowing travel through the hut (because of its range) while *Misty Step* and *Teleport* do.  But I haven't found any explicit support saying that drawing a creature from another plane does not count as casting through the hut.

Related:
[Can Dimension Door be cast into Leomund's Tiny Hut?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132885/can-dimension-door-be-cast-into-leomunds-tiny-hut)

[Leomund's Tiny Hut and familiars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133596/leomunds-tiny-hut-and-familiars)

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Can an Unseen Servant move into Leomund's Tiny Hut?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147359)" and "[Can someone break into a Leomund's Tiny Hut via the Ethereal Plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150462)"

Comment: Are you using "Summon Monster" as a shorthand for multiple spells (Conjure/Summon X), or is this referring to something I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: @Someone It's a 3rd party publisher spell; here's [a link](https://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting/3pp-spells/spells-schwalb-entertainment-llc/summon-monster/) from the SRD website thing

Comment: I'm kinda confused by the close votes? This seems reasonably scoped, the various sub-questions are all greatly related, and answering the first question basically requires answering the second. Is it just that is asks about both the *tiny hut* caster conjuring things and some other caster conjuring things?

Comment: I agree with @Medix2, this question is able to be answered objectively. Either "Yes, your understanding of it is correct" or "No, and here's why" (or, if there's nothing on the topic, "It's up to the GM", but I highly doubt that with this question). There's no ambiguity, and it doesn't have "many valid answers" like the closed-questions page says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *Leomund's Tiny Hut* does not block planar travel or teleportation

Teleportation and planar travel are effects that are specifically blocked by higher-level spells such as [*Mordenkainen’s Private Sanctum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/private-sanctum), which can create these effects (among others) within its area:

> - Nothing can teleport into or out of the warded area.
> - Planar travel is blocked within the warded area.

Several other higher-level spells can create similar effects, but the text of *Leomund's Tiny Hut* doesn't contain anything like this. *Private Sanctum*, at 4th level, is the lowest-level spell I can think of that can block planar travel.

So, to the extent that conjuration involves summoning something from another plane, such an effect would not be blocked by the hut, with one important exception:

### *Leomund's Tiny Hut* prevents entry via the Ethereal Plane

*Leomund's Tiny Hut* creates a dome of magical force, and according to the DMG, all creations of magical force extend into the [Border Ethereal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#BorderEthereal):

> Normally, creatures in the Border Ethereal can’t attack creatures on the overlapped plane, and vice versa. A traveler on the Ethereal Plane is invisible and utterly silent to someone on the overlapped plane, and solid objects on the overlapped plane don’t hamper the movement of a creature in the Border Ethereal. The exceptions are certain magical effects (including anything made of magical force) and living beings.

So if a spell were to attempt to summon a creature from the Ethereal Plane, the spell would be unable to do so *unless the creature to be summoned was already inside the dome* at the time *Leomund's Tiny Hut* was cast.

However, all of the above may be irrelevant, because:

## Conjuration spells do not necessarily involve planar travel

Many conjuration spells that summon creatures don't specify a mechanism by which those creatures are summoned. For example, the relevant part of [*Conjure Animals*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-animals) reads:

> You summon fey spirits that take the form of beasts and appear in unoccupied spaces that you can see within range.

How do the creatures get there? "You summon" them. That's all it says. Given that no mechanism is specified, **the manner by which creatures are summoned by conjuration spells is left entirely up to the DM**. Of course, given that the creatures summoned are "fey spirits", it would be perfectly reasonable to the DM to rule that the spirits are summoned from the Feywild and must therefore be summoned from one plane to another. So you should check with your DM about how they plan to handle this. (Worth noting: supposedly these kinds of spells tend to cause DMs a lot of headaches, to make sure to ask nicely.)

In any case, if your DM rules that summoning involves planar travel, then the above 2 sections should have you covered. (Likewise, the above sections apply to any conjuration spell that *does* explicitly call a creature from another plane, of which there are a few.) And if your DM rules that summoning *doesn't* involve planar travel, then you've got nothing to worry about. In fact, you don't even have to worry about the 9-creature "occupancy limit" of *Tiny Hut*, since that only applies at the time of casting. (Any creatures summoned into the hut would, however, be trapped inside until the spell ends.)

Comment: I'm not convinced that summoning from the ethereal plane would be blocked by the hut. It seems to me this is predicated on the idea that summoning involves movement of some kind. In my mind it's closer to teleportation, the creature instantly appears there. That appears to me to be the only point that would change if the DM rules that summoning consitutues planar travel.

Comment: Hmm.  This also means that even though one can Misty Step into a Hut, one cannot become Ethereal and then enter?  Also, if summoning does NOT involve planar travel, would not some of those spirits come from the Prime?  And if so, would they not be hedged out by the Hut?

Comment: @gszavae As I said, it would ultimately depend on how the DM "implements" summoning in their game.

Comment: @Kirt Yes, you're correct, shifting into the Ethereal Plane won't help you enter or exit the hut. As for summoning that does not involve planar travel, once again it depends on the DM's decision. For example, if they rule that summoning is simply teleporting the summoned creature to you, then the Hut won't block that, since it doesn't block teleportation.

Comment: Wait, why do you think teleportation effects let you out/in?

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Because nothing says they don't.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson That's not an answer.  A *prima facie* reading of " All other creatures and objects are barred from passing through it" would prohibit all travel, including extraplanar travel (e.g. teleportation).  Why do you think that e.g. teleportation is not passing through or creatures that are teleporting aren't part of "all other creatures" or w/e

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil Contrast *Forcecage*, which is superficially similar to an inverted *Tiny Hut* but has explicit mechanics limiting teleportation and planar travel.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson but forcecage has to say that since it allows spells to be cast through it in cage form. tiny hut does not.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson but forcecage has to say that since it allows spells to be cast through it in cage form. tiny hut does not. all the spells you reference allow spellcasting across them, so to block teleportation they have to explicitly state it.

Comment: @John Many teleportation/planar travel spells target the departure point or the thing to be teleported, not the destination. Examples include *Teleport* ("you and up to eight willing creatures of your choice that you can see within range"), *Plane Shift* ("You and up to eight willing creatures who link hands in a circle"), and *Misty Step* (Range: Self). So any of these spells can be used to leave the hut, because you're casting them on something/someone that is inside the hut.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson so what?  target does not mean much. the wording specifically says effects cannot extend in to it. effects, the appearance of creatures at the destination is definably part of the spells effect, just as the radius of a fireball is part of its effects. teleportation cannot extend into it just as the edge of a fireball cannot extend into it.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, it depends on your interpretation of "passing through" the barrier.

A summoned creature is not passing through the barrier any more than they are passing through a wall if summoned inside a building.

The creature can be summoned either inside or outside the hut, but cannot pass through the barrier.